# Name for adaptive simulated annealing that cyclically decreases stepsize, then increases temperature, resetting both after each accepted move?

Tags: optimization, metropolis-hastings, simulated-annealing

I have a model with many discrete parameters between 1 and 99. Each step new parameters are sampled from a discrete uniform distribution with variable stepsize around the current parameter value, constraining the result to be between 1 and 99.

Essentially I initialize the temperature so that only proposals moving down the gradient are accepted and stepsize to 99. Then subtract one from the stepsize each time the proposal is rejected. But if the proposal is accepted, I reset the stepsize to 99.

If there are so many consecutive rejections that stepsize = 1, the temperature is *increased* each rejection until I get an accepted proposal. Then temperature and stepsize are reset to the initial values.

This works surprisingly well for my problem (better than anything else I have tried so far), as it prevents getting stuck in any local optima. Ie, the algorithm will never really converge but all I care about is the best fit.

It is somewhat inefficient due to all the rejections (only about 2% of steps are accepted), but I can just let it run and it will explore indefinitely. There are of course variations like not resetting step size all the way to 99, instead adding 10 each time a proposal is accepted, etc.

If that is unclear I can post some code but it is a pretty simple concept: Start out with large steps and if that doesn't work take smaller and smaller steps, and if that still doesn't find anything allow a step up the gradient to further explore from there.

I was wondering if anyone else had come up with variations on this idea.

Comment: "...only proposals moving down the gradient are accepted" doesn't sound like simulated annealing to me.  It violates the conditions needed to prove SA is likely to converge or go anywhere near a good solution.

Comment: @whuber I agree it is some kind of inverse annealing only after the step size has decayed to the minimum. I was just playing around and found that this worked very well. For my problem (which is discrete, constrained, and stochastic) it gets closer to the correct solution than anything else I have tried. I was surprised it worked.

Answer (score 1):

generally, SA does a random walk with some extra constraints. according to "probabilistic machine learning" by k.p. murphy pp 300, a random search can be surprisingly effective and is in fact advised as a baseline. I guess what you are doing is something inbetween SA and that random search. If it works, it works !

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Perhaps, it works far better than random search though. And if I initialize to known correct values, it will stay in that region.